# Websites with file-upload scripts (and other capabilities) in Firefox - can they get Thunderbird email identities? (Fedora linux)

Tags: linux, firefox, email, security, thunderbird

I'd like to set up an instance of Thunderbird on a Fedora VM (with a VPN). I want it to use ONLY an alias I have set up with the email providers. I think I can do that with TB settings.

But I will still have to use my real credentials to log into the server. So they are in `.thunderbird` somewhere.

I have to deal with websites on that VM that are pretty invasive by nature (rental tenancy applications like 2apply, snug.com, etc). Each are in a Firefox Container.

They all have the facility to browse your system to upload files and documents, or 'drag-and-drop' - i.e. I have enabled those scripts in NoScript, and I have no choice about that.

I'm worried that information will leak from Thunderbird to the websites, particularly my real email address.

I don't really understand what these websites can do on a system - what can they read? Especially as Firefox and Thunderbird are from the Mozilla stable - do they facilitate information exchange (specifically, email addresses) that can leak to the website?

How should I think about this? Is it really a risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your Firefox is ancient, it will have pretty good security against
thieving websites:

- Disk access is only possible via the user interface, meaning that it's
  you that select manually the files to unload.
  A website cannot read files without you knowing about it.
- Add-ons are segregated, each having its own private data area,
  so that one add-on cannot see another's data.

An add-on can only find data that is furnished by the browser, which
will include the browser model and (much) more. Your Thunderbird
information is not part of it.

Note that an add-on can pretty well get enough information from the
browser to uniquely identify it and you. It won't know your personal
details, but it, and other related websites, can always know that it's
your browser that accesses them. The website itself can find out
information such as your IP address.

Comment: That's great info, thank you.